# How do I calculate cpu and gpu performance ?

Tags: cpu, gpu

I want to compare gpu's and cpu's like benchmarks. But I don't get it logic behind this. How can I calculate processing capacity about any cpu or gpu ? What I need to do ?

Answer (score 1):

The performance of CPU's and GPU's are based partly in specefications (i.e. frequency, tdp, etc.) and also the architecture design. Due to different processors using different architectures, specifications won't be able to tell you which processor is faster (i.e. an AMD 4ghz cpu might be slower than an Intel 3.5ghz cpu). To solve this, both CPU's are given the same problem to work on and which ever finishes first is faster. This is a rather simplistic explanation, but it does show the general idea behind bench marking in general. Think of the two CPU's as runners. Two runners may both weigh 120lbs and be 5 foot 9 inches, but they will most likely finish the race at different times. So a benchmark is really just a race between CPU's as to which can finish faster.